# How to prevent iframe from scrolling back up upon iframe refresh?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

Basically, I am using my `html.iframe` element to display incoming new data from a function that is constantly running as a subprocess of my Dash web interface.

I am using the `n_intervals` property of my `dcc.Interval` element to update my `html.iframe` element by using a callback function.

My dash code looks like this:

```
html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Interval(
            id='logger-interval', 
            interval=100, 
            n_intervals=0),
        html.Iframe(
            id='console-out', 
            srcDoc='', 
            style={
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '400'
                }
        )
    ]...
)
```

The problem I have now is that whenever it appends new lines and refreshes the iframe display, the iframe is automatically scrolled to the top. I want it to stay scrolled at the bottom most line, while also allowing the user to scroll up without the iframe being forced to either the top/bottom upon refresh.

Is there anyway I can do this? It seems like by default upon refresh of the element, the iframe will start off at the top, and I can't seem to figure out a way to disable this scroll forcing mechanism.